# Switching two lines in a text file in Java

Tags: java, file

I've been stuck on this for a while and I've finally decided to plead for help.
So I have a small text file and the user wants to switch 2 lines from it, the user enters the indexes of the 2 lines and I have to switch em.
So far my ideas have been to either use replaceALL with 2 regexes
, but A: That probably won't switch them but just end up replacing one with the other, leaving me with a duplicate and B: I have no idea how to locate the nth line using regex;
or use - Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(name)).get(index); to get the two lines but then I'm still struggling with the actual switching process.

Comment: Does it need to work with large files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- `Files.readAllLines` to get all lines as a list
- swap the two elements of the list. e.g. `Collections.swap`
- write all the lines back out to update the file.

If you need to be able to work with large files you could

- Use RandomAccessFile to find the start/end of the lines you need by reading from the start of the file.
- Read the two lines into a buffer.
- Write the two lines out in place, but swapped around.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a large file and need to save memory, you could do this (though it may take longer if second swap line is near the end of the file):

```
File myFile = new File(somePath);
File outputFile = new File(someOtherPath);//this is where the new version will be stored
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
String line;
String swapLine;//first line to swap
int index = -1;//so that the first line will have an index of 0

while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    index++;
    if(index == firstIndex){//if this line is the first line to swap
        swapLine = line;//store the first swap line for later
        //Create a new reader. This one will read until it finds the second swap line.
        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
        int index2 = -1;
        while(index2 != secondIndex){
            index2++;
            line = in.readLine();
        }
        //The while loop will terminate once line is equal to the second swap line
    }else if(index == secondIndex)//if this line is the second swap line{
        line = swapLine;
        //this way the PrintWriter will write the first swap line instead of the second
    }
    out.println(line);
}
```

You could, of course, programmatically delete `myFile` and rename `outputFile` to whatever `myFile` was named on disk afterwards:

```
myFile.delete();
outputFile.renameTo(myFile);
```

I believe this works, but I have not tested it.